# json_encode into object with no value

Tags: php, json, typing

What do I have to put in to get an object with 1 property, but undefined value?

Like so:

```
$data = 'test';
$object = new stdClass;
$object->$data = null;
var_dump(json_encode($postData));
```

gives JSON output of

> "data":{"test":null}

but what I'd like to have is

> "data":{"test"}

Comment: `"data":{"test"}` is not valid json so why would you want that?

Comment: I think the main thing is what you consider being an *undefined value*.  Null is commonly used to represent a value which isn't set (and is the default value as well).  So what is wrong with using null?

Comment: "_is not valid json so why would you want that?_" - 3rd party API :/
Someone decided that this is the format he wants, and their API won't accept anything else. I guess I'll just bypass the issue and alter JSON string output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such syntax in JSON, so no standard JSON function will give you that output.

The definition of JSON is deliberately simple, and explained at https://json.org; to quote:

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> - A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
> - An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence

So, you cannot have a key with no value; but you could have a value with no key, by using a list instead of an object:

```
{"data": ["test"]}
```

In PHP, that would be created like this:

```
$data = 'test';
$postData = new stdClass;
$postData->data = [ $data ];
var_dump(json_encode($postData));
```

Or using an array rather than a `stdClass` object:

```
$data = 'test';
$postData = [];
$postData['data'] = [ $data ];
var_dump(json_encode($postData));
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, when you are assigning a variable as a property of an object, it takes the value of that variable as the name of that property. So, "$object->$data" should be "$object->data" to set the property name as data.

Secondly, you are assigning null value for the property. So, it is outputting the value of the "test" property as null.

Change the code like this and if I am not guessing wrong, you will get the correct output.

```
$data = 'test';
$object = new stdClass;
$object->data = $data;
var_dump(json_encode($object));
```

Comment: That would certainly be a sensible approach, but it won't output the (invalid) JSON requested, it will give `{"data":"test"}` - [try it for yourself](https://3v4l.org/H7aeq)